# How to resolve session timeout error from client side?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

I am stuck in a situation related to session timeout()While user is still active on web page.

What is happening that on clicking a particular link on webpage user is redirected towards a popup page. This popup contains an Oracle form(Basically an applet) and this applet is embedded inside a HTML page .

When user is working on this popup , all requests are going towards the form server which is different than Jboss server . So after some time session times out .

I took the following approach to resolve this issue :

I added this jquery code below in this popup page .

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var timer=0;

function run(){         
    timer++;    

    if(timer == 2){
        $(document).bind('keyup mousemove',function(){        
            $(this).unbind('keyup mousemove');      
            $.ajax({
                url:     'https://bdqap1.acclaris.com/bensol/common/refreshsession.jsp',
                cache:   false,
                data:    'html',
                success: function(data,status) {                       
                }
            });
            timer=0;                                    
        });

    }
}// run ends here

setInterval(run,1000); 
</script>
```

This code calls a link in jboss server on any mouse or keyboard movement on the popup . This should keep session alive while user is active .

But this approach is not working as jquery code is not able to detect any movement over the Applet part . Jquery is not working is applet is in focus .

I wanted to resolve this issue from the client side . Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding and rebinding the event handler every 2 seconds. It might be simpler to simply do the ajax request every 30 seconds (or whatever time is appropriate to prevent the session timing out:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function run(){     
  $.ajax({
    url:     'https://bdqap1.acclaris.com/bensol/common/refreshsession.jsp',
    cache:   false,
    data:    'html',
    success: function(data,status) {}
  });
}// run ends here

setInterval(run,30000); 
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the resolutiojn ofmy problem . I think you did not understand the question .

Comment: Then please can you clarify the question. My code will keep the session open.

Comment: My question is that Jquery event are not working on the Applet part. How will I resolve that

Comment: The applet is taking over the handling of these events and not passing them on to the browser. If you really want to do this based on these events you will need to fire the ajax request from inside your applet code, not from javascript. (Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with applets to know how/if you can do this). Simply doing it on a timer as I've done would IMHO be a better way of solving the issue